# Add and then query temp table from pandas with Snowflake python connector

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a temporary table from a pandas df and then use it in a sql statement

```
import snowflake.connector
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas

with snowflake.connector.connect(
account='snoflakewebsite',
user='username',
authenticator='externalbrowser',
database='db',
schema='schema'
) as con:

    success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(
        conn=con,                    
        df=df,
        table_name='temp_table',
        auto_create_table = True,
        table_type='temporary',
        overwrite = True,
        database='db',
        schema='schema' 
       )

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('select * from temp_table')
```

The error I get:

> ProgrammingError: 002003 (42S02): SQL compilation error:
> Object 'TEMP_TABLE' does not exist or not authorized.

Comment: The easiest way to troubleshoot is to use [Activity/Query History](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-activity.html) and compare the `CREATE TABLE ... ` vs `SELECT *....`. Possible options: 1) Different sessions for create and read(temporary table lives as long as active session) 2) quoted identifier `"`, the table name should match exactly the same as during `CREATE TABLE` 3) lack of schema, the select statement tries to read from different schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write_pandas()` creates a table using the letter case exactly how it is passed in `table_name=`, while the query submitted in `cur.execute()` passes the entire string with the query to Snowflake SQL, and Snowflake SQL capitalizes the object names unless they are written in [double quotes.](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#double-quoted-identifiers)

Therefore, either you create a table using capital letters `table_name='TEMP_TABLE',`
or you query it using double quotes:

```python
  cur.execute('select * from "temp_table"')
```

In this case, you will get your table created in small letters, and you always need to add double quotes to refer to its name.